# Import XML for NFL scores 2018 - New XML?

Tags: php, xml, google-sheets, feed

Last year I was provided with `IMPORTXML` so I can get live scoring updates to Google Sheets.  I went to use it today to prep for 2018 and it's still pulling last year's data.  I'm not familiar how I can get the information needed for this year, if it's changed or if it's just too soon. I was hoping someone with a little more knowledge could maybe guide me or point e in the right direction?

```
=importxml("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml","//g/@eid" )
```

This was one of the fields I used, and it's still pulling 2017.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that XML service is discontinued or not so easy to find.

However this site is a JSON equivalent I believe.

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json

and this site gives live data also and you can choose by date.

http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/game-center/2018090600/2018090600_gtd.json

After staring at the output from the first link, it looks like you can get the matches in play and scheduled from that, and then use the references to select a particular match for the full play-by-play details in the second link.

Below is a function you can use http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json to get the results into Google-sheets and present with selected fields.

To install and use it read the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_a_custom_function

In your sheet pick a cell and enter = ReadNFLResults()

To run the script periodically (say every 2 minutes), follow these instructions https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-periodically-run-a-Google-Script-on-a-Spreadsheet

```
/** Imports NFL results to your spreadsheet Ex: ReadNFLResults()
* @customfunction
*/

function ReadNFLResults(){

  try{

    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json");
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);   

    // Extracts the keys (these change every week)
    var keys = [];
    for(var k in json) keys.push(k);

    // Declare array for results
    var NFLResults =[];

    // Make a Title Row
    NFLResults.push(["Date","Stadium","Time","Qtr","Home Team","Hs1","Hs2","Hs3","Hs4","HsT","Vis Team","As1","As2","As3","As4","AsT"]);

    // Extracts the Games one per line
    for(n=0; n<keys.length; n++){
      var Date = ""+keys[n];
      var Stadium = json[keys[n]]["stadium"];
      var Clock = json[keys[n]]["clock"];
      var TV = json[keys[n]]["media"]["tv"];
      var Qtr = json[keys[n]]["qtr"];
      var Home = json[keys[n]]["home"]["abbr"];
      var Hs1 = json[keys[n]]["home"]["score"]["1"];
      var Hs2 = json[keys[n]]["home"]["score"]["2"];
      var Hs3 = json[keys[n]]["home"]["score"]["3"];
      var Hs4 = json[keys[n]]["home"]["score"]["4"];
      var HsT = json[keys[n]]["home"]["score"]["T"];
      var Away = json[keys[n]]["away"]["abbr"];
      var As1 = json[keys[n]]["away"]["score"]["1"];
      var As2 = json[keys[n]]["away"]["score"]["2"];
      var As3 = json[keys[n]]["away"]["score"]["3"];
      var As4 = json[keys[n]]["away"]["score"]["4"];
      var AsT = json[keys[n]]["away"]["score"]["T"];
      NFLResults.push([Date,Stadium,Clock,Qtr,Home,Hs1,Hs2,Hs3,Hs4,HsT,Away,As1,As2,As3,As4,AsT]);
    }

   // Return array to Google-Sheets
    return (NFLResults);

  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

Here is sample results as of Sept 10, 2018:

[image: NFL results in progress]

Comment: I really hope this link shows the updated scores. However, it is 9:21 p.m EST and nothing has updated. (I would have expected the "p" (which I think stands for possession) to show "ATL")!

Comment: I know "zilch" about NFL  but check this feed and see if any better. <http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/game-center/2018090600/2018090600_gtd.json>

Comment: That last link seems to be giving a live broadcast of plays in individual games rather than just live score summaries which I think you are after.

Comment: Indeed! It has scores and a whole lot more. Essentially the entire play-by-play sequence. I am off trying to parse it it quickly! Cheers!!

Comment: or this may be simpler <http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json>

Comment: its 9:50AM Sept 07 here in Perth Australia - and I find this all a bit funny! :-) - but don't forget to consider to accept or whatever if it all works out...

Comment: Haha! Cheers my Aussie mate!

Comment: So I was able to import json, but there is a lot of extra data that I wouldn’t need. Coming from a newbie POV with very little knowledge. Is there way to grab only certain columns of data?

Comment: @ATS did you mean newbie PHP? yes you can get whatever columns you like. Did you try the simpler link in my updated answer, or the better link provided by theSideline?  Which one looks best for you?

Comment: @ATS On reflection, I think the link provided by theSideline only gives historical results and not live game updates - so be aware of that (if I read them right) :-)

Comment: @bcperth I used the http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json and this is practically what I was looking for, I just would like to use certain columns.  I'm not sure if that's something I do after it's imported into Excel, or something I can do before?

Comment: @ATS ok great. Are you using this data in a PHP program? If so you don't need to import to excel as PHP can read directly to an array. Otherwise explain a little how you are processing the data and I can assist.

Comment: @bcperth In google sheets lm using =importJson with the link provided and it imports the data in one long game after game. No PHP , never used before

Comment: @ATS ok your question is tagged 'PHP' so I assumed PHP.  I will take a look for you, but may be a bit later as I have to do other things for a while. If not today, then tomorrow!

Comment: @bcperth I appreciate as much as you’ve done so far. Sorry I mistagged that one.

Comment: @ATS I made a new script that will load the results and display in google-sheets. Check it out in the response and let me know how it looks.

Comment: @bcperth Will be testing this out later today, if not tomorrow, Can't wait.  It looks awesome!!

Comment: @bcperth this is so great!  Is there an option to add to the script to have it refresh say every 2 minutes?  Is that something that's possible?

Comment: @ATS Great it all works! I added the instructions to run script periodically in reply (I did not test). You might consider also to accept the reply by clicking on the tick just under the vote up/down icons on top left of my reply. This is not compulsory at all, but is considered a nice way to show appreciation of effort.

Comment: @bcperth I’m beyond grateful to you! I clicked the check and up tick as well. I am going to check what you added. Again, thank you for going above and beyond

Comment: @ATS OK great. Its fun for me. After today I will be an vacation for 2 weeks, so if any last minute requests - it has to be today!

Comment: @bcperth will do, if not, have a great vacation!

Comment: This .json link appears to be dead do you happen to have an updated version you could post?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

http://www.nfl.com/ajax/scorestrip?season=2018&seasonType=REG&week=1

Looks like you have to specify the querystring parameters for season and type and week but looks like the output might be the same.

Comment: I think I had a look at this earlier and decided the data was final results of games played for the week specified, and also list of games of scheduled for the week. The links in the other answer provide live updates during play. Maybe check them out a bit and see what you think?   Nice work though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my script. It works well. Don't forget to set up the script triggers to auto run it each minute or however frequently you wish.

```
function GetNFLScore(){

var url = ('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json');
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);   
var bye = "";

// Extracts the keys (these change every week)
var keys = [];
for(var k in json) keys.push(k);

// Declare array for results
var NFLResults =[];

// Make a Title Row
NFLResults.push(["Qtr","Time","Home","Pts","Away","Pts","Pos.","Down","To Go","Yard Line","Note","Network"]);

// Extracts the Games one per line
for(n=0; n<keys.length; n++)  {   
  var Clock = json[keys[n]]["clock"];                 // Kickoff time if pregame, Game Clock if game time
  var Qtr = json[keys[n]]["qtr"];                     // Gamestate (Pre, or Final), Game quater if game time
  var Home = json[keys[n]]["home"]["abbr"];           // Home Team
  var HsT = json[keys[n]]["home"]["score"]["T"];      // Home Total Score
  var Away = json[keys[n]]["away"]["abbr"];           // Away Team
  var AsT = json[keys[n]]["away"]["score"]["T"];      // Away Total Score
  var TV = json[keys[n]]["media"]["tv"];              // TV Network (NBC, FOX, ESPN, ect..)
  var YardLine = json[keys[n]]["yl"];                 // Current scrimage yard line
  var PosTeam = json[keys[n]]["posteam"];             // Team with ball possession
  var RedZone = json[keys[n]]["redzone"];             // Redzone boolean
  var Down = json[keys[n]]["down"];                   // Current Down
  var ToGo = json[keys[n]]["togo"];                   // Current To Go yardage for 1st down
  var Note = json[keys[n]]["note"];                   // Scoring play (Touchdown, Field Goal, Extra Point, Safety)

  // Correcting team abbr
  if( Home == "JAC" ){ Home = "JAX";}                 // JAC > JAX
  else if( Home == "WAS" ){ Home = "WSH";}            // WAS > WSH
  else if( Home == "LA"  ){ Home = "LAR";}            // LA > LAR

  if( Away == "LA"  ){ Away = "LAR";}      
  else if( Away == "WAS" ){ Away = "WSH";}
  else if( Away == "JAC" ){ Away = "JAC";}

  // Clear non-score related game data if game is final
  if( Qtr == "Final" ){ 
    Clock = "";
    PosTeam = "";
    RedZone = "";
    Down = "";
    ToGo = "";
    Note = "";
    TV = "";
  } 
  else if( Qtr == "Final OT" ){ 
    Clock = "";
    PosTeam = "";
    RedZone = "";
    Down = "";
    ToGo = "";
    Note = "";
    TV = "";
  }

  // Display Game data
  NFLResults.push([Qtr,Clock,Home,HsT,Away,AsT,PosTeam,Down,ToGo,YardLine,Note,TV]);
}

// Clear the bottom of the scoreboard from lack of scores caused by bye weeks
var rows = NFLResults.length
for(n=0; n<(17-rows); n++) {
  NFLResults.push([bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye]);   // N'SYNC
}

// Create new tab 'NFL Scores' if it doesn't exist.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var itt = ss.getSheetByName('NFL Scores');
if (!itt) {

    ss.insertSheet('NFL Scores');
}

// Push Scoreboard to spreadsheet
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NFL Scores').getRange(1,1,17,12).setValues(NFLResults);

}
```